# Facebook iOS 7.1 getting error of Bolts

Tags: ios7, cocoapods, facebook-ios-sdk, ios7.1

I am having issue in my project where I am using Facebook SDK with POD

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '2.6.3'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
```

When I am running in iOS 9 it's work perfect, but my project Deployment target is 7.1, so i have tested in that and getting error of Bolts.

Here with attached screenshot of error.

[image]

Comment: How did you add Bolts?